# Discourage page break in tcolorbox theorems

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I would like to penalize, but not forbid a page break in tcolorbox theorems. Is this possible?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[language=german]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{TcbTheorem}{Theorem}{breakable, colback=blue!5, colframe=blue!5, coltitle=red,}{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{TcbTheorem}{First}{}
        \lipsum[1-3]
        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
    \end{TcbTheorem}
        \begin{TcbTheorem}{Avoid Breaking This}{}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{TcbTheorem}
    \begin{TcbTheorem}{Break This}{}
        \lipsum
    \end{TcbTheorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer is not too late.

Environments defined by `\newtcbtheorem` accept an optional argument as their first argument, in the form of a list of `tcolorbox` options. Hence you can specify option `unbreakable` (or `breakable=false`) to locally switch the break-ability.

```
\begin{TcbTheorem}[unbreakable]{Avoid Breaking This}{}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{TcbTheorem}
```